# Soql in Vf page using sForce.connection

Tags: sforce.connection

I am trying to soql in VF page. But I am not getting an result. I have verified my code.

```
<apex:page >

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  

     function soqlQuery(){          
          try{
              var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name from Account",{
                  onSuccess : function(result){
                      alert('I am in 2');
                  },
                  onFailure : function(error){

                  }
              });
          }catch(e){
              alert(e);
          }
      }
      window.onload=function(){
          soqlQuery();
      }
     </script>
</apex:page>
```

Can anyone check and let me know what i am missing out here.

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: your code looks good.. just you need to add `result.getArray("records")` to get the records.

Comment: Have fixed the issue it was bec of sforce.connection.sessionId. When I added the code it worked. But can any one help me to understand what is sforce.connection.sessionId.

Comment: Yes .. actually when we use sforce.connection sometime there is issue with session(i.e. current user session). So if you use `sforce.connection.sessionId` this will assign the current user's session Id and all the sforce.connection will work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of records from result

You need `result.getArray("records")` to get the records

complete code

```
<apex:page >

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  

     function soqlQuery(){          
          try{
              sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}'; 
              var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name from Account",{
                  onSuccess : function(result){
                      alert('I am in 2');
                      var records = result.getArray("records");
                     console.log('==========records======='+records);
                  },
                  onFailure : function(error){

                  }
              });
          }catch(e){
              alert(e);
          }
      }
      window.onload=function(){
          soqlQuery();
      }
     </script>
    </apex:page>
```

and check browser console..

Comment: alert in onsuccess is not working. I am not able to get it displayed. It is getting into onFailure. What is wrong with my code why it is getting fail.

Comment: @Anu check my updated ans.. Issue may be you are getting with session expire.. for this you need to add `sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';`

Comment: is it possible to pass the result to a VF page component. eg here we get the Account list I want to display it on Vf page. For this I need to pass the result to a apex tabel. Is it possible how can we achieve it.

Comment: @Anu then why don't you use controller here.. controller is good option to create list and display in VF page..

Comment: Yes you are right we can use apex class and we can achieve it simply. But I wan to improve the performance of my page. For this I want to control some of the features from JS it self. IF we need to pass it to controller I hope their is no need to so SOQL on VF page.

Comment: then I thing best option to iterate over list in javacsipt and create table in javascript itself and after that add that table in any specific target element check this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164655/generate-html-table-from-2d-javascript-array  @Anu

Comment: So you mean that we can only pick the value of apex component from JS but we can't  put into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38226/discussion-between-sfdcweb-and-anu).

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure whether the sforce.connection.query have callback function. You can use like below

```
var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name from Account");
var records = result.getArray("records");
for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
    var record = records[i];
    log(record.Name + " -- " + record.Id);
}
```

Hope it helps.